# Are there any situations where a selection sort does not sort a list until the nth pass?

Tags: sorting, selection

In my programming book it has the Selection sort run n passes for an n sized list everytime. Is there ever a situation where the nth pass is needed? Wouldn't the n-1th pass swap the n-1th element with the nth element every time?

Answer (score 0):

It needs n-1 passes. 
Total comparisons being (n-1)+(n-2)+……+(n-k)+…3+2+1 =n(n-1)/2 and the complexity is O(n^2)